# How do i get a compiled directive to listen to the variables outside of its scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/QMrrDycuMyEG7cJkCB5f?p=preview

In the page's `MainCtrl` scope, we have a variable defined: `$scope.listen`

Under that, i've got a directive called `titleSetter` which has an attribute `title` which is listening to the `listen` variable. It updates correctly.

Under that, I've got another directive called `listeningComponent`, whose job is also to listen to that `listen` variable, and it has a scope variable `listenertext` which, like the `titleSetter` directive, has `listen` passed into it.

Under that, I've got a stage, which is designed to compile directives into a little stage area. Inside it, there is a `#stage` div, which is where the compiles go. This directive has a link function that compiles the `listeningComponent` into it.

Go ahead and type something in the box above which is bound to the main page's `listen` variable. Everything will update with it... almost. As you can see in the Plunker, the `listeningComponent`, when compiled into `stage`, cannot listen to the `listen` variable.

How do I get it to listen to that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you forgot to define listen in stage scope, i.e. just
`listen : '='` in js, and `listen="listen"` in html.

http://plnkr.co/edit/2BmXDHjINNxaOXy6R7Yb?p=preview

Comment: is there a way, by chance to pass the variable to the compiled variable without actually making it an attribute in the html text string?